# Google's reCaptcha to reduce spam

Tags: php, contact-form, spam, recaptcha

I noticed a huge increase in spam emails coming from my website's contact form and am looking into using Google's reCaptcha method to reduce and/or eliminate this spam.

My website already has a contact form along with a .php file for that form. Here is a snippet of the html code for the contact form:

```
<form class='mailform' method="post" action="bat/rd-mailform.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="form-type" value="contact"/>
             <fieldset>
              <label data-add-placeholder="">
               <input type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                data-constraints="@LettersOnly @NotEmpty"/>
             </label>.............
```

I have registered with Google reCaptcha to obtain a site key and secret key and have added the `<div>` within my `<form></form>` section. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MyKey"></div>
```

I have also added the following to my Head section:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Since the site already has a .php file for this Contact Form, how do I modify the file so that the reCaptcha works properly?

Here is a snippet of the rd-mailform.php file already running for this website:

```
<?php


$recipients = 'email@gmail.com, email@verizon.net';

try {
require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

preg_match_all("/([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/", $recipients, $addresses, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if (!count($addresses[0])) {
    die('MF001');
}

if (preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    die('MF002');
}

$template = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

if (isset($_POST['form-type'])) {

....................
```

Do I only need to modify the above .php file? From my online searching, it looks like I may also have to include the recaptchalib.php library file and upload it to my hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need any library just get recaptcha sending information when you handle form submission.

```
<?php
$secretKey = "Your secret key when you register for recaptcha";

if(!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $secretKey. "&response=" . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']));

    if (!$response->success) {
        // There is a problem implement your logic!
    }
}
```

**Updated :**
// standard.html

```
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-lang="tr"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
      'sitekey' : 'yourSiteKey',
      'theme' : 'light'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So do I simply just add the above code to my existing .php file?

Comment: Yep and use required js stuff in your form template.

Comment: Esatoglu Can you please elaborate on "js stuff"?

Comment: @BrownBag24 please check my answer, I updated and added related view code.

Comment: so I added the above code to my existing php file and added the standard html to my contact form, but it does not seem to work yet. When I check the reCaptcha checkbox and click the submit button, I do receive the email, but with a very long reCaptcha response. And when I don't click the reCaptcha checkbox and then click on the submit button, I still receive the email. Thoughts?